# Symfony 4.4. ExceptionController and PreviewErrorController deprecation

Tags: symfony, twig

After upgrading to Symfony 4.4, I'm getting the following 2 deprecation warnings (only in production) :

```
php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ErrorController" instead.
php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\PreviewErrorController" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use the "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ErrorController" instead.
```

I followed the information provided here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.4.md

```
{#config\packages\twig.yaml#}
twig:
    exception_controller: null
```

But the deprecations are always present, do you know where it can come from?

Comment: Hi, are you using FosRestBundle? For me the deprecation come from there.

Comment: @Spawnrad No, I only use the following fos bundles: "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle" and "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle". I have the latest updates

Comment: With the configuration set to `exception_controller: null` the deprecated notices will be produced by composer when using `optimize-autoloader: true` or running with  `composer -o` or `composer --optimize-autoloader`. This is because each of the class files includes a `@trigger_error()` line and the `autoload_classmap` includes those files during complication of the container `bin/console cache:warmup`, which adds the notices to your `var/cache/env/...ContainerDeprecations.log` when building the service definitions for the container.

Comment: The above also applies to when composer is set to `classmap-authoritative: true` or running `composer --classmap-authoritative` or `composer -a` as it implicitly enables `--optimize-autoloader`

Answer (score 0):

I see a same problem than you into Symfony-Demo : https://github.com/symfony/demo/issues/1032 look at this end of page.

You need maybe change your config/routes/dev/twig.yaml

Before :

```yaml
_errors:
    resource: '@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    ...
```

After :

```yaml
_errors:
    resource: '@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but no it's not that. I have well `resource: '@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'`

Comment: In this commit file ( by Fabien ) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/33271/files you need to add    framework:
       error_controller: 'App\Controller\MyExceptionController'

Comment: I think it's for overriding the Default ErrorController, so I don't need that https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html